# Weird RSpec behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I am experiencing something weird when trying to test a model through rspec. I have the code

```
it "has might that varies by atmost 30" do
  instance.init(100)
  expect(instance.members.count).to eq(1)
  instance.members.each do |member|
    puts "#{member.unit.name}"
  end
  expect(instance.members.count).to eq(1)
end
```

Whenenver I run the above test, both expect methods pass, signaling that there is only a single "member" record associated with the instance, but when I print out the name of each member, it prints a name twice, saying that there is two different members?

EDIT: Also, the method works correctly on the development server, but only have this issue during tests?

EDIT: method in question

```
def init(might)
  transaction do
    self.group.delegations.each do |delegation|
      unit = delegation.unit
      amount = (might / unit.might) * delegation.fraction
      amount = amount.round
      unless amount < 1
        self.members.create(unit: unit, amount: amount)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: what is your database?

Comment: `count` queries the database, what does `instance.members.length` return?

Comment: database is PostgreSQL, and you're right, the length method returns 2, ie. the extra member, but why is this?

Comment: The members array is cached and does not reflect the current state of your database.

Comment: Any idea as to why it stores two members in the array then?

Comment: Could you post the code that's creating/adding the members?

Comment: Maybe `init` is called from another example and the instance's members cache is not invalidated. Print a debug message before creating the member.

Comment: what is that/how is it done? Sorry for my ignorance, but I am fairly new to rails

Comment: Add `puts "creating member"` before `self.members.create(...)`. you should see this output when running your specs, hopefully twice.

Comment: Yea I get that twice, but I dont understand why

Comment: Okay I have found the problem, the "init" method get's called twice, so it adds the delegation from the group twice, but I dont understand why it calls it twice

Comment: Replace `puts "creating member"` with `raise` and you get an error message including a backtrace. This will reveal the other call.

Comment: It just points back to the spec calling the method